# Display web.config setting as HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

My web.config file has the following:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="TermsAndConditions" serializeAs="String">
        <value>&lt;p&gt;
                    My text here...
               &lt;/p&gt;
        </value>
      </setting>
    </MyProject.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Then in the controller I have:

```
ViewBag.terms = Properties.Settings.Default.TermsAndConditions;
```

Lastly, in the view I have:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    @ViewBag.terms
</div>
```

What is being displayed on the webpage is literally the below, rather than the `<p>` tag being converted to HTML:

```
<p> My text here... </p>
```

Any idea how to turn the tags to HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `web.config` to store HTML. Use a separate XML file.

E.g:

```
<SettingsHtml>
   <Value>
       <![CDATA[<p> My text here... </p>]]>
   </Value>
</SettingsHtml>
```

Wrapping the HTML in a [CDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076(v=vs.110).aspx) section will ensure that you don't need to HTML encode the content before it's output.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    @ViewBag.terms
</div>
```

Will HTML encode the `terms` value by default.

Use [@Html.Raw()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.terms)
</div>
```

Comment: It was an unfortunate requirement of my project to have this in the web.config file. Using `@Html.Raw()` fixed the issue I was having. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You've html encoded the data in the XML, so you need to [decode it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx). You'll also need to use `Html.Raw` to output the HTML:

```
ViewBag.terms = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Properties.Settings.Default.TermsAndConditions);

<div class="col-lg-2">
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.terms)
</div>
```